# Can I select the nearest quest to my location in my Pip-Boy?

Tags: fallout-4

I've gone wandering through wasteland finding and pursuing various side missions, and have found myself in the top right corner of the map.

When selecting a quest in my Pip-Boy is there a way to select the nearest one to me, as most of them are way back in the middle of the map?

Comment: Been wondering this myself, but I haven't found a way to sort quests by locale/distance yet though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no way to do precisely what you want, but the the [V.A.N.S.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/V.A.N.S.) Perk is the next best alternative. Activate all the quests, and V.A.N.S. will point you towards the closest one.

Answer (score 2):

As of the current patch, there is no way to sort or select quests by any location based criteria.